# I found a generic way to turn a class into a dictionary, is there a generic way to reverse that process?

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary, reflection

So I'm trying to build a data-mapper style ORM in Swift. I was trying to find a way to turn any entity into a dictionary so I could map that to a database table. I managed to do that with this code:

```
public protocol Entity: class {
    var id: Int? { get set }
}

func unwrap(any:Any) -> Any? {
    let mi = Mirror(reflecting: any)

    if mi.displayStyle != .Optional {
        return any
    }

    if mi.children.count == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    let (_, some) = mi.children.first!

    return some
}

public func serialize<T: Entity>(entity: T) -> [String:String] {
    let aMirror = Mirror(reflecting: entity)
    var dict = [String:String]()

    for child in aMirror.children {
        if let label = child.label where !label.hasPrefix("_") {
            switch unwrap(child.value) {
            case let entity as Entity:
                if let id = entity.id {
                    dict[label] = String(id)
                }
            case let .Some(test):
                dict[label] = String(test)
            default: break
            }
        }
    }

    return dict
}

public class User: Entity {
    public var id: Int?
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var role: UserRole?

    public init(username: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }

    public func assignRole(role: UserRole) {
        self.role = role
    }
}

public class UserRole: Entity {
    public var id: Int?
    var name: String
    var description: String

    public init(name: String, description: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

So now I can do:

```
let newUser = User(username: "NotMyRealName", password: "SomeKindOfPassword")
let adminRole = UserRole(name: "admin", description: "Administrator of the website")
adminRole.id = 1

newUser.assignRole(adminRole)

print(serialize(newUser))
```

Which will print: `["password": "SomeKindOfPassword", "role": "1", "username": "NotMyRealName"]`

That's all well and good, but now I want to reverse this process.

I'd like to write a function that could use like so:

```
let user = unserialize(["username":"Me", "password":"secret"]) as? User
```

Is that possible you think? I understand it might be a bit of a hack if I'd try to bypass the init method, but I'd like to try.

Comment: There may be several ways to accomplish this. What do you want to do with the dictionary?

Comment: I'll be using the dictionary to go back and forth between an Entity object and a SQLite Database table. (Well doesn't have to be SQLite, but for example yes). So I already know how to go from Entity to Dictionary, but now I want to know how to go from Dictionary to Entity...

Comment: Did you consider CoreData?

Comment: Yes I did, and I am still considering it. Truth is I don't understand CoreData very much yet, but from what I've gathered from some tutorials it seems you're kinda obligated to work with (a subclass of) NSManagedObject and I would prefer working with a completely clean class for every Entity.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I would encourage you to give CoreData a try anyway. Yes, you will have to work with NSManagedObject or subclasses hereof, and yes, there is a learning curve to be mastered. But it's a reasonable effort and it will pay off very quickly.

Comment: @Lasse is CoreData just like Entity Framework in C#/.NET?

Comment: @Mafi I don't know Entity Framework but CoreData is a OO wrapper around SQlite with build-in iCloud support.

Comment: @Lasse sounds almost like EF. Sounds great actually, thank you!